# How to make sense of this linear algebra question about union of proper subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble understanding the following;

I want to show that a vector space can never be written as the union of two proper subspaces, were proper subspace refers to being a subspace, yet not equal.

My question partially is, how to make sense of this? How could we even have that two subspaces are proper to each other? Because

$U \subset W$ and $U \neq W$ and $W \subset U$ , $W \neq U$ seems strange. How could this be? Ie, if U is contained in W but not equal to it then how could W be contained in U?

Or is what the question means that $U$ and $W$ are proper subspaces with respect to $V$ itself?

In any case, I want to use that for a union to be a subspace it requires that one of them is a subset of the other at least.

Can anyone help to explain?

Also the answers given help, but I am still confused about when we actually use that fact that union is a subspace if and only if one is contained in the other. Where does this show in the proof ?

Comment: It does mean $U$ and $Wˆ$ are proper subspaces of $V$. The result is more general: it is true for the union of two `subgroups` of a group.

Comment: There is a more general version of this: Suppose a family of subspaces $S$ of vector space $V$ over field $F$ satisfies $\cup S\subseteq V$, and no element of $S
$ contains all others. prove $|S|\geq|F|$

Comment: Let $W=U+V$. Pick $u\in U\setminus V$ and $v\in V\setminus U$. Then $u+v\not \in U+V=W$. Contradiction.

Comment: @dREaM  But how do you know such a u and such a v exist?

Comment: By hypothesis, because there is no containment between $U$ and $V$

Comment: How does U not being equal to W and V not being able to W imply that U and W are not contained in one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's try this. First you have that $2$ proper subspaces of a vector space $V$. Thus $\mathbb{U} \subset V, \mathbb{W} \subset V, \mathbb{U} \neq \mathbb{W}$. And assume that $\mathbb{U}\cup \mathbb{W} = V$. These assumptions imply at once that $\mathbb{U} \neq \emptyset, \mathbb{V} \neq \emptyset$ ,$\mathbb{U} \not\subset \mathbb{V}$, and $\mathbb{V} \not\subset \mathbb{U}$.Thus take $u \in U, u \notin \mathbb{W}$, and take $w \in \mathbb{W}, w \notin \mathbb{U}$, then look at $s = u+w$. We see that $s$ is neither in $\mathbb{U}$ nor $\mathbb{W}$, thus $s \notin V$, contradiction.

Comment: But what If say, U and W were not equal because U had all the elements that W had, but U also had more elements. Then how could we say there is an element in W that is not in U?

Comment: Good points. In my answer, I should add the parts that neither $U$ nor $W$ is a subset of the other then it would be complete.

Comment: I would still really appreciate if you could elaborate on the point about neither being a subset. this is what I am wondering

Comment: Can you please? If you would take the time to finish helping I would be happy to accept the answer. as it is now I don't find it very helpful as I specifically want to know how that part fits ni

Comment: I edited it.See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, your question isn't very precise, but I can guess what you wanted.

**Problem:**

Suppose we have a proper vector subspace $ U \subsetneq W $ and another proper vector subspace $ V \subsetneq W $, then we can prove if $ U \cup V $ is a vector space, then it is necessary that $ U \subset V $ or $ V \subset U $.

**Proof:**

Suppose the contrary that there exists $ u_1 \in U $, $ u_1 \notin V $, $ v_1 \in V $, $ v_1 \notin U $ and $ U \cup V $ is a vector space.

First, since $ U \cup V $ is a vector space, $ u_1 + v_1 \in U \cup V $.

Now suppose $ u_1 + v_1 \in U $, then $ v_1 = u_1 + v_1 - u_1 \in U $, a contradiction.

Now suppose $ u_1 + v_1 \in V $, then $ u_1 = u_1 + v_1 - v_1 \in V $, a contradiction.

Now $ u_1 + v_1 \notin U $ and $ u_1 + v_1 \notin V $ and $ u_1 + v_1 \in U \cup V $, a contradiction.

The only fallacy is our assumption, so we proved our proposition using proof by contradiction.

Comment: Why the down vote? What's wrong with my proof?

Comment: Nothing, +1${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you, but do you have any comment about my second part( ie the example)?

Comment: Nice example! Note that there is still nothing wrong with the fact that the union of any two in the three proper subspaces are vector subspaces, meaning your example does not contradict the proposition.

Comment: Thanks, and finnaly I am wondering, so we are wanting to prove that a vector space cannot be written as the union of proper subspaces, but where do we explcitity use the fact that for union to be a subspace, one must be contained in the other?